# marker not showing on map

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

I am using google maps to point the location of the user. I am not able to find any marker on the app. The marker should point on current location. using the same code as in the link.

https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/intermediate/android-map-app-showing-current-location-android/

this is my screen without the marker

[image]

my entire main activity code is:

```
public class parentTracker extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_parent_tracker);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();


    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        buildGoogleApiClient();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();


    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }



        //Place current location marker
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        //move map camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

        //stop location updates
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {



    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                    // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                    if (grantResults.length > 0
                            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        // permission was granted. Do the
                        // contacts-related task you need to do.
                        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                            if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                                buildGoogleApiClient();
                            }
                            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                        }

                    } else {

                        // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                        Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    return;
                }

                // other 'case' lines to check for other permissions this app might request.
                // You can add here other case statements according to your requirement.
            }
    }


    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Asking user if explanation is needed
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: where is your code? Should we guess it? lol

Comment: Your first link is not working. And you have to show us a bit of your code, otherwise nobody can help you

Comment: sorry :p, edited now

Comment: Show some code instead of image.

Comment: show us your code. not tutorial one

Comment: i tried to changing all the marker code. still not helping

Answer (score 0):

You should first add your marker in the onMapReady method. Otherwise you shall see your marker only after you move and receive a new location.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are getting a valid location in OnLocationChanged?. If so, then you can try to use the refreshMap() method (specified below) in order to put any marker on the map:

```
// Map
private GoogleMap mMap;

// Method that clears all previous markers in the map and put a new marker with the new location coordinates.
private void refreshMap(Location location) {

    // Just double-checking that the map is correctly set and that we have a valid location.
    if (mMap == null || location== null) return;

    // Clearing the map.
    mMap.clear();

    // If there is a valid Latitude and Longitude, then show the marker in that position.
    if (location.getLatitude() != 0.00 || location.getLongitude() != 0.00) {
        LatLng coordinates = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(coordinates).title("Current Position"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinates, 16));
    }
}

// OnLocationChanged
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    refreshMap(location);
}

// Setting of the variable mMap when the GoogleMap is ready.
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
}
```

**NOTE:** Sometimes the first location returned by the "LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates()" will be the last known location. So I recommend to you to keep listening to location updates and stop when a location different from the "last known location" arrives. You can use the method of getting the Last Known location from Fused Location in order to compare the coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Its because your mobile location information is not enabled.Enable it and the code will work